# Managing /data/system/netpolicy.xml: what do these policies mean?

Tags: networking, internet, system

Seems like it wasn't clever of me to restore `Data (policy/stats)` with Titanium Backup. It has all that apps' unique UIDs from my previous system (actually, the same phone, but wiped and flashed) and now I'm starting to think that the same apps now have new UIDs, so the settings may be completely wrong, except the system ones, right? If I remove all the policies from the file, should I expect it to repopulate with defaults? Is this file controlled by that system app which allows to enable/disable cellular/wlan access?

What do all that policies mean? In case of manual setting. They're mostly 2048 and 3840, but there're 2816, 1792 and 768 too.

The reason why I've started to worry about it: Play Store is having some problems with the connection. To be exact, when I download starts it runs with Download Manager *(uid: 10010, com.android.probiders.downloads)* and the manager keeps saying «reconnecting», meanwhile other apps have no problems with the internet access. 10010 has 768 policy + it whitelisted (`<whitelist>...</whitelist>`), but at the same time I see that another app has 768 policy and it's some little game, I restricted it in internet access UI. However, it's not a total connection failure: it can download a couple of megs, then speed drops to a few kbs and only then it starts to say «reconnecting».

Maybe (just maybe) it has nothing to do with netpolicy.xml and it's something else causes the problem, but I don't know what else tbh.

Comment: problem solved by manual deleting all the setting lines and rebooting the device. when you open your system app with internet usage settings, it repopulates the file. actually, it repopulates the file right when you open settings, without reboot. 768 means allow both WLAN and cellular, 3840 – disallow both.

Comment: `netpolicy.xml` file mainly contains settings that are made from **Settings > Network & internet > Data usage** and **Settings > Apps & notifications > Advanced > Special app access > Unrestricted data**. So you can delete the file and make these settings any time to regenerate the file.